# In Windows 8 Metro-Style App Development, how can I use objects from external JS files/libraries?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a JavaScript calendar in a .js file, which I used in an html page and I'm trying to use it on a metro app. How can I import it and call from it in the data.js default file? (The data.js file starts with an "(") And then how can I create a calendar Element to use on the "element" field of the tile item?
If I manage to import into the data.js file, and create an element using createElement function suggested by Microsoft, will it work properly, since it requires that external JavaScript file? If not, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to referencing the script in your HTML page, like so:

```
<script src="/js/calendar.js"></script>
```

you can drag the file from Solution Explorer and drop it at the top of the .js file where you want to use it, and it will provide you with a reference that looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="calendar.js" />
(function () {
    "use strict";
```

Once you have that reference, Visual Studio will give you nice Intellisense for the .js file when you reference its functions.

Comment: Thanks.
I did this but variables created from types defined in calendar.js still give the error that the type is undefined...

Comment: Is the calendar JS library something that's publicly available? If so, can you provide a link to the library, and show some code for how you're implementing it, and in particular the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: Yes it is: http://javascriptcalendar.org/
I added the .js files to my project.
I'm currently using "jsDatePick.full.1.3.js"m which I added the reference to default.html and followed your instructions in "data.js".
My implementations so far is pretty much a copy-paste of "example-full.html" (I didn't want to change much until I got something working).
It gives me error in:
`g_globalObject = new JsDatePick({
            useMode: 1,
            isStripped: true,
            target: "div3_example"
        });`
, claiming JsDatePick is not implemented.

Comment: The HTML part I try to replicate by using createElement and adding it to the sample items content field. (I am not entirely sure this will work, since it requires the JS code in the data.js, which is already dependent from the code in jsDatePick.full.1.3.js . However, if it doesn't, I'm clueless on how to display a calendar on there...)

Comment: Update: I started over and magically stopped complaining about JsDatePick. I must have messed with something that I shouldn't have. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Add the file to the Project in visual studio, the include the JS file script tag in the default.html of your application. You can then use it like any other JS library.

Answer (score 2):

Also, two big things to keep in mind.  If possible try to include the .js source file in your project (like you are doing). Calling out to a CDN or external hosted location will flag you for some security checks you wouldn't normally have to go through.

There is no guarantee the JavaScript library will continue to work over time either.  I have kept older versions of SoundJS and jQuery around for this reason.  I've seen apps throw some errors when newer versions were doing something like DOM Manipulation that flagged some security violations.

Comment: I see, thanks. What if I later need to use an external online API (such as Google Maps)? Would there also any security issues I have to deal with then?

Comment: I have seen people use Google Maps in an iframe with no issues.  If you're looking to take advantage of Windows specific features in Maps there is a new Bing Maps SDK just for Windows 8 here: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/10/03/bing-maps-sdks-for-windows-store-apps-now-available.aspx